# opamp, ADC, level shift problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

I have an input signal with an amplitude of a few mV that I want to filter, amplify and then feed to an ADC ("Analog Signal").

The input signal (Coming though C1) is lifted at 2.5V and the range of the ADC is 0-1.25V. The ADC has a reference voltage pin of 1.25V (it's the LTC2470).

Until now I was using the Adjustable resistor R4 to center the output signal of the opamp by hand. But this solution is not elegant. I would like to remove R3, R4 and the +5V input and manage to center the output without external intervention.

How would you proceed to center the output signal of the opamp to about 1.25/2?

[image: ADC input]

Comment: Second op-amp. First amp to scale the signal, second one to set offset.

Comment: Why not just replace R3+R4 with a 1.333 M resistor (or 1M 1% + 332K 1%)?

Comment: Change the 2.5V on pin three to 1.25/2, and change the ground on C4 to be that voltage as well.  This is still in the common mode input voltage range of your op amp.

Comment: Is your input an AC signal? What frequency range? Does the input signal (to the left side of C1) have a DC offset? Do you need to measure this DC offset with the ADC?

Comment: @ScottSeidman: If Vin+ in not in the middle of the supply voltage, doesn't it reduce the available range for my signal?

Comment: @FiddyOhm: the input signal AC with a few mV of amplitude and an offset of 2.5V. I am only interested in the amplitude of the signal around that 2.5V offset

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I am not convinced by the accuracy of this solution, that is why I used an adjustable resistor. I was more looking for a solution that uses the V_ref = 1.25V of the ADC

Comment: @KevinP -- yes, you obviously have less range.  There is no way to center the signal closer to ground without having less range unless you have a negative rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want to use the 1.25V reference for the offset. This is basically the comment Scott Seidman made in schematic form:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ4qh4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input common mode voltage is fine- it sits at 625mV fixed which is well within the range. Maximum input voltage is about 9mV peak. The op-amp output can't swing quite down to the negative rail with the load of the ADC input so you would get slightly more range by biasing it up by a smidge, but probably not enough to be worth bothering with given the large Vos uncertainty of that particular op-amp.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear solution. I have two more questions: 1) Why do I have to set the ground of C4 to 0.625 as Scott Seidman mentionned? 2) Would you recommend to use that solution, or keep the "summing amp" you suggested before?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary or desirable- I would keep it grounded sans some kind of rail splitter buffer configuration. Maybe Scott could explain. This is probably a slightly better solution than just putting the 1.333M resistor in because the 0.625V derived from the 1.25V is low-pass filtered (so maybe less noise than wherever your 2.5V source is coming from) and based on the ADC reference (so slow variations cancel out).

Comment: Because at high frquency, your output would go to ground, and my understanding is that you would want it to go to 0.625